# Web3Modal WalletConnect - Connected state lost when changing page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ethereum, cryptocurrency, web3modal

My [Web3button](https://web3modal.com/) is located in the header component of my nextjs website. When i log in or log out and stay on the same page, it works great.

However, if I log out, click on one of the main nav menu links also located in the header and try to reconnect, the button seems to lose the connection state. In this case, the Web3button stills show "Connect Wallet", even if the connection has been initiated. If I try to click on the button again, the modal tries to connect again and shows an error message. I have to fully refresh all the page so the button and the modal get refreshed.

[image: Connection Declined]

Please find below my app.js where the modal is instantiated:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../redux/store";
import { Web3Modal } from "@web3modal/react";
import Meta from "../components/Meta";
import UserContext from "../components/UserContext";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  EthereumClient,
  w3mConnectors,
  w3mProvider,
} from "@web3modal/ethereum";
import { configureChains, createClient, WagmiConfig } from "wagmi";
import { arbitrum } from "wagmi/chains";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);
  const scrollRef = useRef({
    scrollPos: 0,
  });
  const chains = [arbitrum];
  const projectId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const { provider } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })]);
  const wagmiClient = createClient({
    autoConnect: true,
    connectors: w3mConnectors({ projectId, version: 2, chains }),
    provider,
  });
  const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiClient, chains);
  useEffect(() => {
    setReady(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {ready ? (
        <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <ThemeProvider enableSystem={true} attribute="class">
              <UserContext.Provider value={{ scrollRef: scrollRef }}>
                <Layout>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>
              </UserContext.Provider>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </Provider>
        </WagmiConfig>
      ) : null}
      <Web3Modal
        themeVariables={{
          "--w3m-accent-color": "#8358FF",
          "--w3m-background-color": "#131740",
        }}
        projectId={projectId}
        ethereumClient={ethereumClient}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

And my header file :

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import DarkMode from "../mode/DarkMode";
import Logo from "./../../public/images/logo.png";
import WhiteLogo from "./../../public/images/logo_white.png";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import {
  isChildrenPageActive,
  isParentPageActive,
} from "../../utils/daynamicNavigation";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAccount, useEnsName } from "wagmi";
import { Web3Button } from "@web3modal/react";
import DropDownInfos from "./fragments/DropDownInfos";

export default function Header() {
  const { address, isConnected } = useAccount();
  const { data: ensName } = useEnsName({ address });
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const [isCollapse, setCollapse] = useState(null);
  const [hydrated, setHydrated] = useState(false);

  // window resize
  useEffect(() => {
    setHydrated(true);
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      if (window.innerWidth >= 1024) {
        setToggle(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

/* Some code */

            <div className="ml-8 hidden items-center lg:flex xl:ml-12">
              <Web3Button label="Connect" icon="show" />
```

What I would like to have happen is that a refresh of the button and the modal should show the actual connection state.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. Just place the createClient, ethereumclient, provider outside the function MyApp..or you "Memoize" it.. look at the documentation carefully. it was placed outside the function MyApp.

```
//rest of the code

const chains = [arbitrum];
  const projectId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const { provider } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })]);
  const wagmiClient = createClient({
    autoConnect: true,
    connectors: w3mConnectors({ projectId, version: 2, chains }),
    provider,
  });
  const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiClient, chains);

const function MyApp() {} //...rest of the code
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).